# my combo box is duplicating the strings

Tags: combobox

help, combobox just keep adding items, i tried using removeallitems but after that i cant put anything on the first combobox

```
public class Function {

    public void combofillsect(JComboBox section, String year){
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String query;

    try{

        query = "Select Section from asd where Year=?";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root",""); 
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, year);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
        section.addItem(rs.getString("Section"));

        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        section.addItem(e.toString());

    };        
}




Function funct= new Function();      
         {funct.combofillsect(jComboBox1,String.valueOf(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem()));    }
```

why cant I post image?

Answer (score 0):

Are you programming in C# ? If it's the case then you can use the function Clear like that : `yourComboBox.Items.Clear()` to delete all the current items. I don't know if it will solve your problem but your technique of getting the data from your database seems weird to me, if you used a dataset you could have done `dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count()` to get the number of entries and then set the exit condition of your loop like this -> `counter < dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count()`, and set a counter++ at the end of your while (maybe that's why you say your combobox won't stop filling, but I don't know what do the `next()` function).

I don't know the C# code but there is my VB.NET function :

```
Public Function getAll() As DataSet
    ConnectionDB()

    Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand
    cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table", Connect)//Connect is a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, or my connection string
    Dim adapter As New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dataset As New DataSet

    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
    adapter.Fill(dataset)
    adapter.Dispose()
    cmd.Dispose()
    Connect.Close()
    Return dataset
End Function
```

I don't know if I helped you but I didn't really understood what your problem was and you didn't even mentioned the language you use ^^ Good luck

Edit : and if you can't post images, that's because you don't have yet 10 points of reputation, you can get informations about reputation here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation, but you still can post the link of a picture it will allow users to click on it